# How to Generate a collider for a loop .obj in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am unable to add a rigidbody and a collider to a loop or ring shape object in unity 5.
Can anyone tell me how to do it.
I want my obj to follow the gravity and have a collider which 
Is a circle and a hole in between.

I get the following error:
`Non-convex MeshCollider with Non-kinematic Rigidbody is no longer supported in unity 5.`

Comment: What is your code?

Comment: I didn't wrote code yet but i added my external obj with generate collider options and added rigidbody it goes through everything and gives an error saying non-convex MeshCollider with non-kinematic rigidbody is no longer supported in unity 5.

Comment: You can generate tiny mesh colliders to make one collider. There are many convex colliders plugin in the asset store for this

Answer (score 1):

It's because non-convex `MeshCollider`s with non-kinematic `Rigidbody`s are no longer supported in Unity. Specifically, this means that you can't have a concave collider, such as the one you want have physics. If it doesn't need to have physics, just be collided with (which is what the kinematic bit means), then that is fine, but you cannot have a rolling torus I'm afraid.

The only way to achieve what you want is to make a compound collider from a series of convex collider. Search for tools that can perform Concave mesh decomposition, then use the meshes generated to create your torus.

Comment: Is there any sort of alternative i want my torus to have gravity and move by wind or water flow.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a potential solution.

Comment: Can you tell me a free name i was unable to find.

Comment: The following leak contains an implementation that should work for you: https://github.com/gradientspace/geometry3Sharp